# What is the max distance between two conductors in vacum to close electrical circle

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

Assuming having one wire connected to the + side of a battery and another one wire connected to the -, what is the max distance between the wires so electricity will still flow from - to the + . Is it equal to the touch distance which is not zero . Or it greater then the touch distance

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751703/2451

Comment: Hi daniel. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic I am soory i closed it becuase it said i can ask a new one so i thought i can deleted the old one and ask a new one

Comment: No problem. This is an ongoing issue: [Related meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13577/2451).